# Relay array or transistor array

Tags: transistors, relay, stepper-motor

I do a lot of 2 colour 3D printing and usually manually change the colour. Just trying to think of a way to automate the process for minimal effort, and limited modifying of my 3D printer.

I want to take the extruder stepper motor output from my 3D printer (the actual driving pulses) and multiplex to one of two steppers.

Then will have some middleware to listen for tool changes and switch the output to one of two steppers.

**Now my question is, what would be the best choice?**

### Relay Array

[image]

**PRO:**

- Can't see an issue electronically
- Are cheap
- Easy to source

**CON:**

- They are quite bulky
- Lots of wires

### Solid state relay

[image]

**PRO:**

- More compact than magnetic style relay

**CON:**

- Bit more expensive
- Lots of wires

### Transistors / Transistor Array IC

I'm fairly new to electronics, but experienced enough to know transistor rarely work as simply as a manual switch / relay. Also not sure what transistors I would use as these motors are usually quite high current.

**PRO**

- Compact
- Easier to expand
- Minimal physical wires
- Lowest cost?

**CON**

- Unknown usage / complexity
- Homemade PCB